# Transpose HTML table depending on device orientation

Tags: html, css, html-table

Say I have a table like this:

```
x A B C D E F
1 a b c d e f
2 g h i j k l
```

Now when device is in portrait orientation (or simply width of the window is too small) I want to display this table like this:

```
x 1 2 
A a g
B b h
C c i 
D d j
E e k
F f l
```

Is it possible to achieve this without the use of JavaScript?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @AlonEitan was there any context for that link? i didn't see it at first, but i'm going to take a wild guess here and you're implying mrpyo should be using named grid columns and rows to assign locations to the grid items?

Comment: @worc Exactly, but since the OP didn't provide the HTML structure then I didn't know what exactly to suggest, but I think grid box + media queries will probably be a good approach

Comment: i don't think an html structure here is necessary to make a more complete suggestion. it would definitely be more helpful, though, to see how much mrpyo was able to figure out before asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a grid system to create some tables and display them by breakpoint. For example using Boostrap 4 :

```css
.row > .col, .row > [class^="col-"] {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-none d-sm-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">A</div>
    <div class="col">B</div>
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">D</div>
    <div class="col">E</div>
    <div class="col">F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">a</div>
    <div class="col">b</div>
    <div class="col">c</div>
    <div class="col">d</div>
    <div class="col">e</div>
    <div class="col">f</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">g</div>
    <div class="col">h</div>
    <div class="col">i</div>
    <div class="col">j</div>
    <div class="col">q</div>
    <div class="col">l</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-sm-none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">A</div>
    <div class="col">a</div>
    <div class="col">g</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">B</div>
    <div class="col">b</div>
    <div class="col">h</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">c</div>
    <div class="col">i</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">D</div>
    <div class="col">d</div>
    <div class="col">j</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">E</div>
    <div class="col">e</div>
    <div class="col">k</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">F</div>
    <div class="col">f</div>
    <div class="col">l</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit 2023-August: Chrome and Edge now display this correctly. Firefox still doesn't give the cells enough height. Safari ignores the writing mode of the cells.

---

CSS allows this but none of Edge, FF, or Chrome does it right. Chrome ignores the writing mode of the cells, FF doesn't give the cells enough height, and Edge makes the rotated table super tall.

http://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/z0fhj7gq/3/

```js
let state = 0;
change.onclick = function() {
  outer.style.writingMode = (state ? "horizontal-tb" : "vertical-lr");
  state = !state;
}
```

```css
td,
th {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

```html
<button id=change>rotate
</button>

<div id=outer style="writing-mode:horizontal-tb; border:1px solid red;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could absolute-position everything and use a media query to use a different set of CSS coordinates, but that's insanity, and is no longer an "HTML table".

Answer (score 0):

learn `grid`. this is very easy.

```css
div {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width:300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  div {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width:100px;
}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>X</span>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
  <span>d</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>f</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>g</span>
  <span>i</span>
  <span>j</span>
  <span>k</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>h</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, but it's not semantic and I believe css has to be crafted specifically to the table dimensions (it isn't dynamic).

Comment: it also doesn't reorient the header column/rows.

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox:

```css
table{ 
  width:100%; 
}
tbody{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
tr{
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
}
td, th{
  display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  tbody{
    flex-direction: column;
  } 
  tr{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  td, th{
    flex: 1;
  }
}

/* DEMO styling */
td, th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
  height: 30px;
}
tr:nth-child(2n){
  background: #eee;
}
tr:nth-child(2n + 1){
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
 <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Annual Sun Hrs</th>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>NYC</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>2534</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Toronto</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>2066</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>LA</td>
       <td>USA</td>
       <td>3254</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Bogotá</td>
        <td>Colombia</td>
        <td>1328</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>São Paulo</td>
        <td>Brazil</td>
        <td>1893</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Santiago</td>
        <td>Chile</td>
        <td>2807</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Sydney</td>
        <td>Australia</td>
        <td>2468</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Berlin</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>1626</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>1633</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Madrid</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>2769</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a realistic answer (but maybe it is...?).

Looking at the ASCI art of the table, it seems to me that if one were able to transform both the table and its individual heading and data cells like this:

```
table.rotated-table,
table.rotated-table th,
table.rotated-table td
{
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

You'd be left with the cells in the relative orientation you wanted. The only (major) problem is that the browser positions rotated elements based on their unrotated size and shape, so that would need to be solved for. If you had perfectly square table cells, this could work.